# Using PHP for getting difference between values in first and second rows of a sorted query

Tags: php, html, mysql

Sorry for the rather long title.

I have the current table in my database: 
[image: Table]

I then use the following PHP code to display the information on my website:

```html
<?php

function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = true) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);
    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;
    $string = array('y' => 'year','m' => 'month','w' => 'week','d' => 'day','h' => 'hour','i' => 'minute','s' => 'second',);
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {if ($diff->$k) {$v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');} else {unset($string[$k]);}}
    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
 return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($conn,"ai-database");
// if ($conn->connect_error) {die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `steam` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
 $cards = $row['cards'];
 $backgrounds = $row['backgrounds'];
 $emoticons = $row['emoticons'];
 $gifts = $row['gifts'];
 $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
}

echo "
    <div class='category'>
      <h2>Steam Collection</h2>
      <p class='info'>
        Last Updated: <span>" . time_elapsed_string("@" . $timestamp) . "</span>
      </p>
      <div class='item'>
        <div class='title'>Cards</div>
        <div class='stat'>" . number_format($cards) . "</div>
      </div>
      <div class='item'>
        <div class='title'>Backgrounds</div>
        <div class='stat'>" . number_format($backgrounds) . "</div>
      </div>
      <div class='item'>
        <div class='title'>Emoticons</div>
        <div class='stat'>" . number_format($emoticons) . "</div>
      </div>
      <div class='item'>
        <div class='title'>Gifts</div>
        <div class='stat'>" . number_format($gifts) . "</div>
      </div>
    </div>
 ";

?>
```

After a bit of css, I get something a little like this:

[image: Display]

I'm wanting to gather the first and second rows after ordering it by id (Desc), Find the difference between the two values and display it on the website.
I'm hoping the result should look like this:

[image: My hopes and dreams]

I've tried using the following, but I feel it looks rather messy and probably bad practice too.

```html
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `steam` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 2";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
 if($i==0){
  $cards = $row['cards'];
  $backgrounds = $row['backgrounds'];
  $emoticons = $row['emoticons'];
  $gifts = $row['gifts'];
  $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
  $i+=1;
 } else {
  $cards2 = $row['cards'];
  $backgrounds2 = $row['backgrounds'];
  $emoticons2 = $row['emoticons'];
  $gifts2 = $row['gifts'];
  $timestamp2 = $row['timestamp'];
 }
}

?>
```

Is there a cleaner and more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use MySQL?

e.g.

```
SELECT
(
    (SELECT cards FROM steam ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) 
    - (SELECT cards FROM steam ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1) 
) AS cardsDiff
```

Edit: You can comma separate into a single query. Then no extra variables are required in PHP.

Edit 2: Scratched up the same table / data as shown, see below:

```
mysql> DESC steam;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| cards       | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| backgrounds | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| emoticons   | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| gifts       | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| timestamp   | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM steam;
+----+-------+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------------+
| id | cards | backgrounds | emoticons | gifts | timestamp           |
+----+-------+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 |   191 |         419 |       187 |    32 | 2015-04-04 16:40:42 |
|  2 |   192 |         419 |       187 |    41 | 2015-04-04 16:40:42 |
|  3 |   190 |         351 |        20 |    56 | 2015-04-04 16:40:55 |
+----+-------+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    -> (
    ->    (SELECT cards FROM steam ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
    ->     - (SELECT cards FROM steam ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1)
    -> ) AS cardsDiff,
    -> (
    ->    (SELECT backgrounds FROM steam ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
    ->     - (SELECT backgrounds FROM steam ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1)
    -> ) AS backgroundsDiff,
    -> (
    ->    (SELECT emoticons FROM steam ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
    ->     - (SELECT emoticons FROM steam ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1)
    -> ) AS emoticonsDiff,
    -> (
    ->    (SELECT gifts FROM steam ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
    ->     - (SELECT gifts FROM steam ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1)
    -> ) AS giftsDiff,
    -> (
    ->    (SELECT timestamp FROM steam ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
    ->     - (SELECT timestamp FROM steam ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1)
    -> ) AS timestampDiff;
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
| cardsDiff | backgroundsDiff | emoticonsDiff | giftsDiff | timestampDiff |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
|        -2 |             -68 |          -167 |        15 |            13 |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I **am** using MySQL, But having a query for each difference it a little too much code than I'm looking for. Instead I've gone for the idea suggested by Norbet Van Nobelen. But thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Then, comma seperate them? Seems you can do what you need in a single query without having to cache values php side.

Comment: Could you explain this a little?

Comment: I just saw the edit, Thanks for explaining the comma part, But I don't understand how I can use the "giftsDiff" variable when I echo the rest of the data?

Comment: The query uses aliases to give names to the columns returned in the select. So here we would have $row['cardsDiff'], $row['backgroundsDiff']...

Comment: Thanks for the edits and explanation, Updated the correct answer to yours. You've also taught me something new today, Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me you have a pretty clean version. You could make it a bit nicer by introducing an object for your record instead of having many parameters as you have now.

The current version could then look like:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `steam` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 2";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$recordArr=array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $recordObj=array();
    $recordObj['cards']=$row['cards'];
    $recordObj['backgrounds'] = $row['backgrounds'];
    $recordObj['emoticons'] = $row['emoticons'];
    $recordObj['gifts'] = $row['gifts'];
    $recordObj['timestamp'] = $row['timestamp'];
    $recordArr[]=$recordObj;
}


?>
```